# error CS0117: 'BindingFlags' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperty'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, uwp

I'm trying to port a Unity 5.3.1 mono project to Windows Store. Here is a line of code that I can't fully resolve:

```
            var pia = T.GetTypeInfo().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
```

`BindingFlags.GetProperty` seems not to be there. According to the .Net 4.5 documentation, this enum property should be there. I have no idea what will happen to the code if I drop the `GetProperty` method.

Is there an equivalent which will be compiled by Unity3D?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have your code distinguish the platform it is running on. While in the Editor, Unity will compile your code against the Mono framework, while during build for WinStore it will compile against .NET 4 or something.
No matter what you write, your code won't compile for one of those platforms.

You need to have different code for the two platforms. For example:

```
#if UNITY_METRO
var pia = T.GetTypeInfo().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
#else
var pia = T.GetType().GetProperties(...);
#endif
```

Comment: Thomas, I already did this. :-) It looks like all invoke members of this enum are just not there.

Comment: (CreateInstance, GetField, SetField, GetProperty, SetProperty). I try to compile an Universal 10 app.